# About a weak topology on TVS

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological vector space and suppose $P$ is a separating family of seminorms on $X$. Denote by $\sigma(X,P)$, the weak topology on $X$, the smallest topology on $X$ that makes each $p\in P$ continuous with respect to $\sigma(X,P)$.

**My question is this.** Is $\sigma(X,P)$ compatible with the algebraic structure of $X$? If yes, can you please explain me why.

Comment: The addition must be continuous under all seminorms on $X$ right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convergence in the weak topology is given by convergence in all of the seminorms in $P$.

Suppose that $x_j\to x$, $y_j\to y$ weakly. For any $p\in P$,
$$
p(x_j+y_j-(x+y))=p((x_j-x)+(y_j-y))\leq p(x_j-x)+p(y_j-y)\to0.
$$
So addition is continuous. If $\lambda_j\to\lambda$ in $\mathbb C$, we have
$$
p(\lambda_jx_j-\lambda x)\leq |\lambda_j|\,p(x_j-x)+|\lambda_j-\lambda|\,p(x)\to0.
$$
This shows that scalar multiplication is continuous.

Comment: Thanks for helping me once again.More power. Are you then referring $(x_j)$ as a net?

Comment: You are welcome. And yes, unless there some special property (like when you have a metric space) in a topological space you test continuity on nets.

Comment: ahh I see...:)Thank you for reminding me the first sentence of your answer. Its great!

Comment: One more, I think you are referring to $y_j\to y$ and not $y_j\to 0$.