# About a Weak Topology of a Vector Space

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

Let $X$ be a real vector space and suppose $P$ is a separating family of seminorms on $X$. Denote by $\sigma(X,P)$, the weak topology on $X$, the smallest topology on $X$ that makes each $p\in P$ continuous with respect to $\sigma(X,P)$. It can be shown that $\sigma(X,P)$ is a Hausdorff topology compatible with the vector space structure of $X$, see for instance [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/379018/about-a-weak-topology-on-tvspart-2) and [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/373174/about-a-weak-topology-on-tvs).

**Question.** How do we construct a base of convex open neighborhoods  of $0$ in $X$ for the the weak topology $\sigma(X,P)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each seminorm $p$ gives you convex open sets $\{p<t\}$, for various positive numbers $t$. Take all of these sets, and you'll have a sub-basis of neighborhoods. (From which a basis is obtained by taking finite intersections).

Comment: It means that the basic element is of the form $({p_1<t_1})\cap \cdots \cap ({p_n<t_n})$ for some $p_1\cdots,p_n\in P$ and some postive numbers $t_1,\cdots,t_n.$ Right?

Comment: @juniven Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @juniven Every open subset of the line that contains 0 also contains an interval of the form (-t,t).

Comment: @juniven Same thing, because p is never negative anyway.

Comment: @ user75064. Thank you, I got it already because for a seminorm $p$ on $X$ and $t>0$, $\{p<t\}=p^{-1}([0,t)).$